# Forwarding a client to the same SignalR instance in Ocelot

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, signalr, scaling, ocelot

We are considering using Ocelot as an API Gateway.
Our environment is being hosted on Kubernetes. One of the micro services is signalR-Hub.
Scaling this hub (more than one pod) is required, yet it is still important that clients would contact the same pod and keeping the connection open.

I have seen that [ocelot does support websockets and SignalR](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/websockets.html).

But what abut contacting the same signalR instance (Pod). Is that possible?

Comment: session affinity is not going to work if your clients are behind a proxy; which seems to be the case.

Comment: What about [sticky sessions](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/loadbalancer.html)?